# QT: How to get data from socket tcpserver at port 1000

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

[image: Figure 1]

I listened the 1000 port with hercules terminal then the data came out.

Now I am coding the program in QT as below

```
void SocketTest::Test()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));
    qDebug()<<"Connect!";
    socket->connectToHost("192.168.0.44",1000);
    if (!socket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        qDebug()<<"error"<<socket->errorString();
    }
}
```

and it shows- "socket operation timeout"

My host ip is 192.168.0.44 port 1000 and My computer ip is 192.168.0.5.

How can I get data as in figure 1 with QT? and please show me some examples because I am a noobie in this field.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, 192.168.0.44 is the IP of the client, not the server.  Try connecting to 192.168.0.5:1000 instead.

Comment: Could you please recommend me on QT code please. And Thank You for the answer.

Comment: It appear  "Host not found". Could you recommend me for more please

Comment: If you cannot connect to either IP, then either there is something wrong with your network connection, or the connection is being blocked by a firewall/router.  Eitehr way, this sounds more like a networking issue, not a coding issue. Can you ping either IP from your client machine?

Comment: I can ping the ip 192.168.0.44 then 192.168.0.5 is my computer IP. And 192.168.0.44 working as client mode and 192.168.0.5 is working at server mode. Could you recommend me for more please.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to the sever,the best approach is to receive data in an asynchronous mode by connecting the `readyRead()` signal of the socket to a slot :

```
connect( socket , SIGNAL(readyRead()),
        this, SLOT(tcpReady()) );
```

From the Qt documentation :

> This signal is emitted once every time new data is available for
>   reading from the device. It will only be emitted again once new data
>   is available, such as when a new payload of network data has arrived
>   on your network socket, or when a new block of data has been appended
>   to your device.

You can read data in the slot which is connected to `readyRead` signal :

```
void SocketTest::tcpReady()
{
    unsigned long long bytesAvailable = socket->bytesAvailable();
    char buf[bytesAvailable];
    socket.read(buf, bytesAvailable);

    for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
        qDebug() << buf[i];

}
```

Comment: I coding by the same as you recommended me the result is the error and show as A link image http://upimage.us/server/php/files/errorlink.jpg

Answer (score 0):

On your `readyRead` slot you can use the `readAll()` function to retrieve all data available on that socket.

If you need its as a `char` array, just use `QByteArray::data()`;

Example connecting to Google:

```
Client::Client(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(readyRead()));
    socket->connectToHost("google.com", 80);
    if (socket->waitForConnected())
        socket->write("HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n\r\n");
}

void Client::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
    qDebug() << data.data(); //Gives a copy of the QByteArray as char array
}
```

And here you can see the result:

[image]